# Get a button to vanish into the distance upon click

Tags: android, animation, button, scale

I am trying to simply get a button to vanish into the distance upon click. Here is my code. What is wrong?

```java
package com.mycompany.myapp;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button mainButton1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.mainButton1);

        mainButton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Button button = (Button) v;
                    button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using mobile version of AIDE

Comment: which button mainButton1 or button ??

Comment: mainButton2. I also want to animate the button as it disappears slowly into the top of the screen and into the distance can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case are you try to hide mainButton1, Try this code.

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity 
    {

     Button mainButton1 ;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            mainButton1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.mainButton1);

            mainButton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                       // Button button = (Button) v;
                        mainButton1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
        }
    }
```

**difference between gone and invisible**

INVISIBLE:

This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes.

GONE:

This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes.

Comment: Thank you very much that did exactly what I wanted to do except I want to animate The disappearance as it's disappearing off into the distance can you help with that?